# Using light cream instead of milk in crepes?

Tags: milk

I have light cream with 15% fat. How can I use his cream instead of milk in crepes?

Do I need to use water and what percentage?

Comment: What kind of crepes?  Do you have a base recipe you use?

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ: These crepes: http://allrecipes.com/recipe/french-crepes/ Of cource if you have something better to recommend it would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that recipe, there are 2 cups of milk, and 2 tablespoons of butter.

The difference in fat from dairy in going from milk to light cream at 15% fat is about 3 tablespoons of fat (and therefore, about 3 tablespoons less water).

You are almost quite likely going to get a quite similar outcome if you eliminate the butter, and maybe add a tablespoon or two of water.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One thing I didn't understood: how much cream I should add, 2 cups?

Comment: Yes, that is how I ran the numbers.